# In Eclipse with StatET- can a Project be changed from R Project to R Package Project?

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

Can an R project in Eclipse (StatET) be changed from *R Project* to *R Package Project* after it's creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is sufficient to

- right-click on the project and select Properties,
- then edit the 'R Project' section to specify the name of your package
- and indicate the root folder of your package (called 'R base folder')

After applying the settings your R Project will have become an R Package Project.

Comment: I am honore to get a reply by the creator himself. :-)

Comment: The "R Project" section does not seem to appear for regular R-projects.

Comment: For the "R Project" section to show, I had to edit the .project.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know R or StatET, but what I do know is that the type of Eclipse project is defined by the project nature which is stored in the .project file in the root folder of the project. If you edit this file you will see how the project nature is set. Create a project of each type you are interested to get the correct project nature class, and then just set it to your desired project nature and save it. Your project is now changed.